# Is SATA 6GB/s Supported on Mid-2010 MBP?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata, macbook-pro, high-definition

I am planning on buying the http://www.ocztechnology.com/ocz-vertex-3-sata-iii-2-5-ssd.html (240gb) and I just wanted to check that I could achieve the maximum read/write speeds of the SATA 3. To be able to do so, I believe that you have to have SATA 6GB/s support, which I am not entirely sure that my Macbook Pro (Mid 2010) has.

Please can you tell me if my MBP has SATA 3, SATA 6GB/s, support?

TIA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Find your MBP specs at this site](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/index-macbookpro.html), I would find it but you do not have enough information in your Question. I doubt it has Sata 3

Comment: Thanks, it says 'Int. HD Interface: Serial ATA (3 Gb/s)', does that meant that it only has SATA 3GB/S?

Comment: @max_ Yep, it supports Up To 3gb/s, but not 6gb/s

Comment: Is there a way of enabling Sata 6gb/s?

Comment: No, not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I also have a Mid-2010 MacBook Pro and I'm about to upgrade to an SSD [Agility 4] with SATA III. The MBP only has SATA II which only means it has speed limitations that won't allow it reach the speeds of the SATA III SSD. In summary, it is very compatible.

By the way, that is why I bought the 256GB Agility4 SSD which is reasonably priced as it compromises some speed for cost. Its the best value for money you will get for this particular upgrade